# Is there a way to call a function when a slider is used in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a settings view, where I use a [Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq5RB.jpg) to change a variable. Is there a way to execute code only when the variable is changed with the slider? I tried .onchange() and the problem that I have is, that even if I don't use the slider, but change the variable with another [Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQNpJ.jpg) Input, the code is executed.

```
 Slider(value: $noteLength, in: 0.1...3.01, step: 0.1)
                            .onChange(of: noteLength, perform:  { value in
                                defaults.set(value, forKey: "noteLengthEx1")
                                levelIndex = 4
                            })

Picker("Level", selection: $levelIndex) {
    ForEach(0 ..< levelOptions.count) {
        Text(self.levelOptions[$0])}
            .onChange(of: levelIndex, perform:  {
                levelIndex = 1
                noteLength = 1.0})
}
```

The code is a bit simplified, but if I use the Picker, noteLength will be changes to 1 and so the .onchange of the slider will be executed. That part I am trying to avoid.

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: You could store separate view variables for the slider and the picker. And use them both to update the viewModel value you actually want to get. That way you would know when the slider value was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use computable in-inline binding with side-effect for this (and you can remove onChange at all), here is a demo

```
 Slider(value: Binding(get: { noteLength }, 
     set: { 
        // willSet side-effect here       // << here !!
        noteLenght = $0
        // didSet side-effect here       // << here !!
     }), 
    in: 0.1...3.01, step: 0.1)
    .onChange(of: noteLength, perform:  { value in
        defaults.set(value, forKey: "noteLengthEx1")
        levelIndex = 4
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you have to use a different variable for that as far as I know.
actually if you change externally the noteLength I think is also adjusting the slider. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the slider is also adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Toggle() and Picker() and solved it the same way. Took a little time to figure it out, so for anyone who is having the same issue:

```
Toggle("Notes can be the same", isOn: Binding(get: {equalNotes}, set: {
    equalNotes = $0
    // side-effects here
    }))
                    
Picker("tone difference", selection: Binding(get: {toneDifferenceIndex}, set: {
    toneDifferenceIndex = $0
    // side-effects here
}), content: {
    ForEach(0 ..< toneDifferenceOptions.count) {
        Text(self.toneDifferenceOptions[$0])
                          }
                      })
```